# React app shows a blank screen after adding redux-persist

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-persist

I am working on this social media MERN website. I am using redux-persist to store the state locally after updating it. Below I have given three code snippets from three different files.

**Here is my code for redux-persist:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  PERSIST,
  REGISTER,
  PAUSE,
  PURGE,
  REHYDRATE,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import authReducer from "./state";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

export const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER, REHYDRATE],
      },
    })
  },
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**Now I am using the "store" and "persistor" in the src/index.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import {store, persistor} from "./persistor";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**Here is App.js code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { ThemeProvider, CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";

// import Sample from "./Sample";
import HomePage from "./scenes/HomePage/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./scenes/LoginPage/LoginPage";
import ProfilePage from "./scenes/ProfilePage/ProfilePage";
import { themeSettings } from "./theme";

function App() {
  const mode = useSelector((state) => state.mode);
  const theme = useMemo(() => {
    createTheme(themeSettings(mode));
  }, [mode]);

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/profile/:username" element={<ProfilePage />} />
          </Routes>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried removing redux-persist and MUI themeProvider, the app works fine.
The problem is that the screen is going blank (white screen and root div is empty when I inspect the website) after adding redux-persist. I have seen the docs of redux-persist and some blogs online and implemented the redux-persist according to my understanding.
Now I don't know if the problem is with redux-persist or with MUI themeProvider.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Here is the github repo for my code: https://github.com/ppratham0811/Sociopedia-project

Thank you

I am just trying to make redux-persist work properly and not show the blank screen.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you check out [How To Debug React App](https://dev.to/colocodes/how-to-debug-a-react-app-51l4). Check the developer console of the browser, and try to backtrack the issue from there.

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced the same issue that waste my time a lot because the browser console was also clear and has not errors.

And after research I found that there are the possibility that we make an error in following steps:

1. **Incorrect setup of redux-persist**: Ensure that you have followed the
   instructions for setting up redux-persist correctly and that your
   store configuration is set up properly.
2. **Incorrect configuration of the PersistGate component**: Ensure that
   you have passed the *persistor* object to the *PersistGate* component,
   and that the loading prop is set to ***null*** or some other loading
   component.
3. **Async setup of your store**: If you are using an async setup of your
   store, it may take some time for the store to be loaded, and this
   can cause a blank screen. To solve this, you can wrap your
   PersistGate component in a Suspense component with a fallback UI.
4. **Data corruption:** If your persist data is corrupted, it can cause the
   app to show a blank screen. You can try clearing the storage and see
   if it resolves the issue.
5. **Incorrect root reducer**: Make sure that you have passed the persistedReducer
   (the result of calling persistReducer) to the createStore method instead of the
   root reducer.

so in my case I found that I did the mistake No.5

But in your case you did mistake No.2 which means you have to pass loading={null} to PersistGate in your index.js [`<PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>`]

so your index.js should look like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import {store, persistor} from "./persistor";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```